How can i add a custom select in PHPMaker code
I'm currently trying to modify an order entry system made in PHPMaker, the problem is that I don't have the .pem files for the project so I'm trying to add an input directly in the code to take the value and save it in the database but it doesn't work for me.
I tried this:
function LoadFormValues()
    {

        // Load from form
        global $objForm;
        $this->GetUploadFiles(); // Get upload files
        if (!$this->idempresa->FldIsDetailKey) {
            $this->idempresa->setFormValue($objForm->GetValue("x_idempresa"));
        }
        if (!$this->idestablecimiento->FldIsDetailKey) {
            $this->idestablecimiento->setFormValue($objForm->GetValue("x_idestablecimiento"));
        }

// The rest of the fields that pkpmaker generates.................

        /*if (!$this->idcategoria_orden->FldIsDetailKey) {
            $this->idcategoria_orden->setFormValue($objForm- >GetValue("x_idcategoria_orden"));
        }*/
        
    }

`function AddRow($rsold = NULL)
{
$this->idcategoria_orden->SetDbValueDef($rsnew, $this->idcategoria_orden->CurrentValue, NULL, FALSE);
rs = ($rsold == NULL) ? NULL : $rsold->fields;
        $bInsertRow = $this->Row_Inserting($rs, $rsnew);
        if ($bInsertRow) {
            $conn->raiseErrorFn = $GLOBALS["EW_ERROR_FN"];
            $AddRow = $this->Insert($rsnew);
            $conn->raiseErrorFn = '';
            if ($AddRow) {

                Get insert id if necessary
                $this->idorden_tra->setDbValue($conn->Insert_ID());
                $rsnew['idorden_tra'] = $this->idorden_tra->DbValue;
                if ($this->imagen->Visible && !$this->imagen->Upload->KeepFile) {
                    if (!ew_Empty($this->imagen->Upload->Value)) {
                        if (!$this->imagen->Upload->SaveToFile($this->imagen->UploadPath, $rsnew['imagen'], TRUE)) {
                            $this->setFailureMessage($Language->Phrase("UploadErrMsg7"));
                            return FALSE;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->getSuccessMessage() <> "" || $this->getFailureMessage() <> "") {

                // Use the message, do nothing
            } elseif ($this->CancelMessage <> "") {
                $this->setFailureMessage($this->CancelMessage);
                $this->CancelMessage = "";
            } else {
                $this->setFailureMessage($Language->Phrase("InsertCancelled"));
            }
            $AddRow = FALSE;
        }
}`


<input type="text" name="x_idcategoria_orden" id="x_idcategoria_orden" value="<?php echo $orden_tra->idcategoria_orden->EditValue; ?>">

